# How to remove special characters in json data python

Tags: python, json

I am reading a set of data from a json file. Content of the json file looks like:

```
"Address":"4820 ALCOA AVE�            ",
"City":"VERNON�   "
```

As you can see that it contains a special character `�` and white space at the end. While reading this json data, it is coming like:

```
'address': '4820 ALCOA AVEï¿½             '
'city': 'VERNONï¿½   '
```

I can remove the whitespace easily but I am not sure how can I remove the `¿½`. I do not have direct access to json file so cannot edit it and even if I had access to json file, I would talk couple of hours to edit the file. Is there any way in python we can remove this special characters. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please show us *exactly* how you are reading the data and how you are displaying the result, including the relevant code, what terminal settings (or if you have supplied the text to a GUI or something, etc etc).

Comment: The question mark in a diamond is a special replacement character that is used to mark a character that could not be decoded properly. Make sure your file is properly encoded and you are viewing it with the right encoding set. JSON has to be in UTF-8, -16, or -32.

Comment: The character � is a *placeholder* used by text-viewing programs to indicate that they don't have a proper glyph to show that character with. So the file contains *some* unusual character, but it's probably not *intended* to show up as �.

Comment: Also, make sure you understand Unicode encodings: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html . There is a *very* good chance that simply saying "I can't figure out what this thing is doing in my data, therefore I will handle the problem by just removing it from the data" is *hiding a larger problem*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regexp

```
    import re
    address = re.sub(r"[^\x20-\x7E]", "", "4820 ALCOA AVEï¿½ ")
    print(address)
```

Comment: Can you explain what does `[^\x20-\x7E]` means

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somewhere upstream wasn't handling character encoding properly and ended up with replacement characters... You may need to keep an eye out in case it mangled more important parts of the text (eg. accented characters, non-English letters, emoji).

For the immediate problem, you can load the JSON data with the utf-8 encoding, then strip the character `'\ufffd'`.

```
   value = value.strip().strip('\ufffd')
```

If the replacement characters also appear in the middle (and you want to delete them), you might want to use `replace()` instead.

```
    value = value.replace('\ufffd', '').strip()
```